# Why am I not getting Cross domain error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page which has an Iframe. ( [**here it is**](http://jsbin.com/axozOli/7/edit))

They are both at different domains.

**Page A:** domain = http://jsbin.com/

It hosts an Iframe with domain : `Example.com`

`<iframe src='http://example.com' id='a'> </iframe>`

However - when I try to access the iframe content via :

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
  console.log($("#a").contents().find("*").length)
});
```

I **do** see response :

[image]

Question :

why am I **not** getting an Error about access different origin ?

*Comment : 
It seems that I can't access the content of elements , but i'm positive that I should have got a cross domain error.*

*relative info :* chrome Version 30.0.1599.66

Comment: the cross domain error - comes from ajax calls

Comment: @RoyiMindel Error should come for accessing content of differnt domain content

Comment: Firefox generates no error either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get an error because the frame hasn't yet loaded so there isn't really anything to block. Try to access it after it loads and you'll see the expected error.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#a").load(function(){
   console.log($("#a").contents().find("*").length)
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uQARiWu/1/edit

Comment: What a foolish mistake of myne :-)